# How to return Geoposition instead of IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> or Task<Geoposition>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I've created a [Windows Runtime Component (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt609012.aspx) in my javascript UWP app, but am having trouble getting it to return the result I want. It builds fine, but on debugging, null is returned, instead of the Geoposition object.

Since the function below needs to be called in my javascript app, it seems I [can't use the async keyword,](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/how-to-expose-async-methods-in-a-windows-runtime-component/) but I can do it in a wrapper:

```
 public static Geoposition GetGeolocation()
    {
        Geolocator _geolocator = new Geolocator();
        MapLocation mapInfo = null;

        _geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;

        try
        {
            Geoposition currentPosition = GetGeopoisitionWrapper(_geolocator).Result;                     
      //      Geoposition currentPosition = GetGeopoisitionWrapper(_geolocator).AsAsyncOperation().GetResults(); 

            //other stuff needing currentPosition, and another async function call

            return currentPosition;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Wrapper:

```
   private static async Task<Geoposition> GetGeopositionWrapper(Geolocator g)
    {
        Geoposition currentPosition = await g.GetGeopositionAsync();                     // get the raw geoposition data

        return currentPosition;
    }
```

Javascript function call:

```
function getLocationForMap() {
    Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator.requestAccessAsync().done(
        function (accessStatus) {
            switch (accessStatus) {
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.allowed:
                    var result = SampleComponent.Example.getGeolocation();
                    break;

                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.denied:
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Access to location is denied.", "sample", "error");
                    break;

                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.unspecified:
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Unspecified error!", "sample", "error");
                    break;
            }
        },
        function (err) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log(err, "sample", "error");
        });
}
```

The reason why I need to do this part in C# is because one of the function calls I need is missing (perhaps the developers forgot to include it) from the javascript API, but exists in C#.

Comment: Can you tell me what function call is missing? I can let the geopositioning team know.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm trying to call Windows.Services.Maps.MapLocationFinder.findLocationsAtAsync(pointToReverseGeocode). At MapLocationFinder level, it's returning undefined. Documentation here implies it should work in javascript: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.services.maps.maplocationfinder.findlocationsatasync.aspx

Comment: I checked with the maps team. `Windows.Services.Maps.MapLocationFinder` is intended to be used in conjunction with the XAML MapControl. If you are writing a JS app, they recommend using the [Bing REST Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx) which were designed for JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, you can't use await. But you can work with promises. You have to work with Windows Runtime datatypes for JS/C# interoperability to get it work. It sounds more complicated than it is:

Change your C# code in your windows runtime component like this:

```
public static  IAsyncOperation <Geoposition> GetGeopoisitionAsync()
        {
            Geolocator g = new Geolocator();
            return g.GetGeopositionAsync() as IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> ;                        
        }
```

or if you want to access the geopostion in C# before passing it to Javascript like this:

```
public IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> GetPositionAsync2()
        {

            return Task.Run<Geoposition>(async () => {
                Geolocator g = new Geolocator();
                var pos =  await g.GetGeopositionAsync();

                // Do something with pos here..

                return pos;
            }).AsAsyncOperation();
```

This method can be called directly from your JS App. Make sure you set the location compatibility and reference the component project from the JS App.

The call - based on your sample code - looks like this:

```
function getLocationForMap() {
    Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator.requestAccessAsync().done(
        function (accessStatus) {
            switch (accessStatus) {
                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.allowed:

                    // call the WinRT Component
                    var rc = RuntimeComponent1.Class1;

                    // use promises to wait for completion
                    rc.getGeopoisitionAsync().then(function (res) {

                        // access the props of the result
                        var m = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(res.coordinate.latitude);

                        // show latitude in message box
                        m.showAsync();

                    });

                    break;

                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.denied:
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Access to location is denied.", "sample", "error");
                    break;

                case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.unspecified:
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Unspecified error!", "sample", "error");
                    break;
            }
        },
        function (err) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log(err, "sample", "error");
        });
}
```

Works on my machine :-)
See full working sample based on your code here: https://github.com/DanielMeixner/so/tree/master/JSAppGeolocation

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply! It works, but do you know how to get back the Geoposition object in the C# code? The ultimate plan is to get the latitude and longitude values from it and do some reverse geocoding before returning the result. I've tried Geoposition currentPosition = g.GetGeopositionAsync().GetResults(), but it always returns null.

Comment: Hi! I adjusted the sample above. You can access the position if you follow the code above. I also updated the sample on Github. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much, Daniel!!

Comment: This works perfectly! Was having a difficult time with the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that **Location Capability** is set using your manifest (Package.appxmanifest file):

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">

   // You should have this
   <Capabilities>
     <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
   </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Why stop there? The method name should also be renamed too. `GetGeopoisitionWrapperAsync()` or something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I have location enabled, and have requested permission in the javascript portion of my app. I can't use the async keyword in the main function, since I need to call it in my javascript app. I've edited my original post for clarification. The reason why I need to do this part in C# is because one of the function calls I need is missing (perhaps the developers forgot to include it) from the javascript API, but exists in C#.